# Rails 3 Mapping an Array of Files in Public Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fastcgi

I have a rotating image as a banner on my webpage, which goes through a directory and returns a random image from the './public/images/banner' directory.  This line of code worked while I was running my application on Passenger but broke when trying to switch over to FastCGI.

Here's the line in my app/views/layouts/application.html.erb that is causing the issue:

```
<img id="header-picture" src=<%= "/images/banner/" + Dir["./public/images/banner/*.png"].map { |file| File.basename(file) }.shuffle.first %>>
```

I get the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert nil into String)
```

If I change it to something like:

```
<img id="header-picture" src="/images/banner/example.png">
```

The website runs correctly.

I think that I'm not going through the directory properly or maybe I'm not mapping the array properly. I'm not really sure how to troubleshoot it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `Dir["./public...."]` it's looking for that path relative to the current ruby script being run. Your current server setup might be running out of a different working directory. It's safest to always force it to search relative to your app's root. So change `Dir["./public/images/banner/*.png"].map` to something like this instead:

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/public/images/banner/*.png")].map
```

or

```
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "public", "images", "banner", "*.png")].map
```

Comment: Thanks,definitely solved the issue. I was on that path, but didn't quite get there.  I really appreciate the answer.